# Prototyping board

Tags: pcb, identification, stripboard, protoboard

Looking for small prototyping board (soldering) with all holes connected (and user have to destroy unnecessary connections). How is this type of boards called?

Answer (score 6):

It's called [Veroboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripboard) or [Stripboard](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1DVCC_enGB367GB368&sugexp=chrome,mod=16&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=stripboard).
You can get it from any decent electronics supplier (Digikey, Farnell, Sparkfun, Adafruit, etc)

**More information**
[Stripboard tag wiki](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/stripboard/info)

Comment: Oli, Google links are not appreciated. You get a million hits, and then what? I'd prefer to have just one relevant link.

Comment: Not appreciated by who? ;-) In this case the Google link is in *addition* to the descriptive Wiki link, to give an example of how easy it is to find a source of cheap stripboard. It may not add anything in *your* opinion, but I can't see how it detracts from the answer.

Comment: Not appreciated by "the community" :-). What it basically says is "look, here's a million links, *you* find it out". I think it's much more helpful to give some descriptive information from 1 or 2 links, and *then* he knows what to Google for if he wants to learn more. The way it is now the answer is just two links, WP and Google, and if I would flag your answer it may well be deleted for that reason. We want the information *here*. That's not just my opinion, that's what moderators think too.

Comment: I know it's short, but the basic answer to the question *is here* in this case. The OP asked "what the prototying board was called with the holes connected.." *was called* (there was also a hint of a shopping question which was why threw the google link in and mentioned sources) I gave the answer to this. I also wrote a [descriptive tag](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tgs/stripboard/info) on Stripboard as I was answering the question FWIW. I agree with what you have to say in general, but I think this simple answer to a simple question is fine in this case.

Comment: The complete answer could have consisted of just the word "stripboard" and also be correct. *I* would have added a picture, and maybe pointed out that there are variants with e.g. each time three holes connected, again with a picture. You could mention that "Veroboard" is actually a brand name, and that what is called veroboard often isn't stripboard, but insulated pads (picture).

Comment: @Steven - yes, I could have done all this here, but instead I spent some time writing the tag wiki (linked to above) to give all this information and more. I do respect your opinion, but I really don't think it's necessary to go into great detail here when the actual question was just a quick one about the name, and detailed information is (now) so readily accessible in the Tag Wiki. A good/correct answer doesn't always have to be long winded. I'll add a little more info and point to the tag though, if that'll keep you happy ;-)

Comment: OK. Thanks for the wiki update. Nice write-up.